# WAMP setup to send mails locally

Tags: php, html, email

I want my script to be able to send emails from WAMP to mail services such as yahoo,gmail etc.I heard that gmail has an SMTP to do that, i dont know how to setup my WAMP to do that.Below are my files
***HTML sample code file***: http://pastebin.com/e50wt0u0
***sendmail.php:*** http://pastebin.com/8iTga04Y

Comment: You need to use an SMTP mail library not `mail()`.  Gmail does allow remote SMTP for something like this (although it may be difficult to get it to work on localhost).  Check out PHPMailer: http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/sending-email-with-phpmailer-and-smtp

Comment: A recent project of mine used this PHP-Login script which uses PHPMailer to send mails via an external SMTP server (namely Gmail): https://github.com/panique/php-login - this should have all the code you need although my build only successfully mails from staging server not from localhost.

Answer (score 3):

You can send mail from localhost with sendmail package , sendmail package is provided with XAMPP by default. So if you are using XAMPP then you can easily send mail from localhost.

For example you can configure `C:\xampp\php\php.ini and c:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini` for gmail to send mail.

In `C:\xampp\php\php.ini find extension=php_openssl.dll` and remove the semicolon from the beginning of that line to make SSL working for gmail for localhost.

In php.ini file find [mail function] and change

```
SMTP=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
sendmail_from = my-gmail-id@gmail.com
sendmail_path = "\"C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.exe\" -t"
```

Now Open `C:\xampp\sendmail\sendmail.ini.` Replace all the existing code in sendmail.ini with following code

```
[sendmail]

smtp_server=smtp.gmail.com
smtp_port=587
error_logfile=error.log
debug_logfile=debug.log
auth_username=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
auth_password=my-gmail-password
force_sender=my-gmail-id@gmail.com
```

Now you are done!! create php file with mail function and send mail from localhost.

PS: don't forgot to replace my-gmail-id and my-gmail-password in above code with your id and password. Also, don't forget to remove duplicate keys if you copied settings from above. For example comment following line if there is another sendmail_path : `sendmail_path="C:\xampp\mailtodisk\mailtodisk.exe"` in the php.ini file